# Как найти все td под th?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="monday">Понедельник</th>
    <th class="tuesday">Вторник</th>
    <th class="wednesday">Среда</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9:00</td>
    <td>9:00</td>
    <td>9:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10:00</td>
    <td>10:00</td>
    <td>10:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Делаю календарь(с разбивкой по неделям). С возможностью выбрать время и закрасить его.
Столкнулся с тем что не понимаю как по нужному `<th>` классу(не `id`) находить все входящие в него `<td>`.

Как это можно сделать?

Скажем будет у меня переменная `blockedTimes` которая содержит в себе заблокированные часы в опред. день `["wednesday", "10:00"]`. Через такую штуку планирую закрашивать ячейку в красный.

Answer (score 1):

Кратко отвечая на вопрос "как по нужному `<th>` классу(не id) находить все входящие в него `<td>`" - с помощью `table td:nth-child(N)`

Исходя из задачи, рассмотрим код:

```js
function draw() {

  // предположу, что данные по дням статичны, всегда возвращается monday, tuesday, wendsday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday
  let blocked = [
    ['9:00', '10:00'], // понедельник
    ['9:00'], // вторник
    ['10:00'], // среда
    [], // четверг
    [], // пятница
    ['10:00'], // суббота
    [] // воскресенье
  ];

  let tds = document.querySelectorAll("table td")
  tds.forEach(element => {
    if (blocked[element.cellIndex].includes(element.innerText)) {
      element.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;")
    }
  })
}

draw()
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="monday">Понедельник</th>
    <th class="tuesday">Вторник</th>
    <th class="wednesday">Среда</th>
    <th class="thursday">Четверг</th>
    <th class="friday">Пятница</th>
    <th class="saturday">Суббота</th>
    <th class="sunday">Воскресенье</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9:00</td>
    <td>9:00</td>
    <td>9:00</td>
    <td>9:00</td>
    <td>9:00</td>
    <td>9:00</td>
    <td>9:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10:00</td>
    <td>10:00</td>
    <td>10:00</td>
    <td>10:00</td>
    <td>10:00</td>
    <td>10:00</td>
    <td>10:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Переменная `blocked` - массив, соответствующий дням и заблокированному времени (окрашиваемому) для дня, в примере: для понедельника заблокированы 9:00 и 10:00, для субботы - 10:00, а для четверга и пятницы нет заблокированного времени

Соответствия для массива находим с помощью `cellIndex`, `element.innerText` отвечает за то, что содержится в `td` (предполагается, что время в виде 9:00, 10:00 и тд, соответствующему формату данных в массиве `blocked`)

Примеры, которые я привел, можно улучшить в плане чистоты кода, но они наглядно демонстрируют работу с `DOM` в рамках поставленного вопроса, [демонстрация](https://codepen.io/pogorelove/pen/eYzjEYm)